# Existing friction free method of forever caching images in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I would like to be able to rename an image for every release by either place 1) the checksum or 2) the version in the filename.  This will allow me to set Expires headers for all of my images without having to worry about cache invalidation on the client side.  I would like to be able to do this without physically renaming the files and changing all the references.  There are a couple of approaches that could be taken:

1. URL rewriting
2. Post build step to rename images and replace links in files

Is there something like this that already exists for ASP.NET?

Answer (score 0):

We take a slightly different approach. For the site assets that are part of the build process (eg--stuff integrated into master pages), we use a custom Url.ResolveImageUrl() that:

a) Points it to the right CDN "root" (eg--local for dev/ci, production CDN type stuff for production)
b) Affixes a version number query string if requested. This can be set actively (read from config) or passively (read assembly version).

This gets you to the same place as new "versions" of the files have a new URL thanks to the query string. The downside, at least with our implementation, is that visitors to an updated site lose any cached assets they might have had, but we didn't have the resources to work out how to make it intelligent enough yet maintain the frictionless theory. So, if you've got an app that deploys multiple times a day, that won't work so good. But something that drops once a month is probably palatable.